# Resizing the subview in a view

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a view in cocoa. This view holds a sub view in it which is created through code and this subview holds tabbar items in it. SO view -> subview-> tabbaritems.

I want that when I resize the view the subview resizes and the tab bar inside that subview also resizes.

The subview is resizing but not the tabbar items.

Answer (score 2):

For whatever view you want to resize with the superView set the constants
     NSViewWidthSizable  and  NSViewHeightSizable to the view need to be resized.
 Using bitwise OR operator combine the constants and set it to the AutoResizing property of the view to get the combined effect of height and width.You can also set these things in your IB itself if you create those views in it.

```
 NSUInteger unitFlags =  NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable;
[yourView setAutoresizingMask:unitFlags];
```

So for your problem set these AutoResizing masks to all your tabbaritems in your subView

Comment: @Varun can you re edit your question to add a little bit of code about  how did you add your tabbar items

Comment: Yes! Saved me so much time with this one.